# Mysql2 0.3.15 TypeError: can't convert nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to create a new Rails 4.1 project with `mysql2 0.3.15` and get the following Error and stack trace. When I force `mysql2 0.3.14` there are no errors.

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `connect'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:910:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/usr/local/Cellar/Gems/1.9/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my `database.yml` file

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: "asdf"
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: dev
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock 

production:
  <<: *default
  database: prod
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

My MySQL client library is 5.6.16 on OSX 10.9.2

**UPDATE**
If I specify `password`, `host`, and `port` in my `database.yml` file this error goes away. Are these now required for some reason?

Comment: Usually indicates a missing or invalid string variable somewhere that the driver expects. The issue may not be in the database.yml but one of the other driver or environment config files (i.e. where you setup mySQL). Not the same issue, but related https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/issues/183

Comment: Is there any reason why it would work find with mysql2 0.3.14? I looked at the differences in the tags, but nothing is really standing out https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/compare/0.3.14...0.3.15

Comment: The error still exists with `rails 4.1.1`

Comment: When you install the gem, did you give it the location of the DB and have you verified that was correct for the newly installed version? I'm wondering if this is actually a socket issue - have you verified that the /tmp/mysql.sock file exists? If you specify a host name other than localhost (even 127.0.0.1) it will try and connect in TCP mode instead of using the local socket. Setting the host could be overriding the need for the socket and resolving your issue. Note: the port number will not be used if the socket is being correctly picked up

Comment: Also not sure why you have quotes around your password - does it work without them? If none of this works and you are still interested in finding the issue can you provide your new version of database.yml in your update?

Comment: @dsatch thanks for your help! It was actually a system configuration error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I turns out I had hardcoded my `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME` rather than letting the gems install in the appropriate `rbenv` folder. Since I had both ruby 1.9 and 2.1.1 installed, when I installed the new `mysql2` gem, the C extensions were compiled against 2.1.1 and caused the above type errors when I tried to connect to the DB. Removing `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME` and reinstalling my gems under the `.rbenv` folder fixed the issue.